# Any text editor where I can collapse (fold) PHP array?

Tags: windows, text-editor, php

Are there any PHP text editors where I can expand or collapse multi-level arrays?
In Notepad++ I can do it with comments or if constructs but not with array variables. Does there exist a program like that? thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) does that. Notepad++ used to be my favourite but recently I've started to prefer SublimeText - and this is on of the reasons. SublimeText has a free non-time limited trial; a per-user (rather than per-machine) licence is $70 but I'm thinking it may be worthwhile due to the greatness of Sublime).

Here's a screenshot of how Sublime Text shows multi-dimensional PHP arrays; each of those three arrays is identical but in a different state of collapse.
[image]

Comment: it seems a very good editor. do you know something else for free?

Comment: Forever free no - you can legally and morally use the free trial of this for a couple months anyways. Legally I can't comment on longer than that but morally testing is questionable much past that.

Comment: @JB-Franco Is free a hard requirement? (If so good to mention it in the question to get better answers)

Comment: No it's not a requirement!

Comment: for further information this capacity of a text editor is called _Code folding_. I have seen that also _Ultra Edit_ have this ability applied to arrays!

Comment: @NickWilde: I suspect you could get Notepad++ to do this by tweaking the folding styles for the php language definitions.

Comment: @Brian quite likely. However it is only *one* of the reasons I'm preferring Sublime lately.

Answer (score 4):

**[SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/)** editor (Windows) also does this.
A shot with php array:

[image: Php array]